# android studio 4.0.1: Android resource compilation failed

Tags: android, ionic4

I have recently installed Android Studio 4.0.1 on Windows.

I import existing app which need to update something on it and I face a problem (Android resource compilation failed ) while trying to run it.

**So I tried these solutions:**

- I cleaned the project and rebuild it.
- I did (invalidate caches/restart).
- I attached image with problem.

[image: here is image]

Comment: Your question will attract more attention if you pay more attention to proper spelling and formatting.

Comment: This screenshot is pretty useless. Please build from console and provide an actual error log.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in my images in android studio
and I did like this
delete your images and replace them by a new image(for me that image was
been default icon android)
and run your project again
I should say this
newest gradle have problem in run